# Upgrade to 15.10

Tags: upgrade

During an upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10 My laptop crashed and I rebooted.

It finished booting at the tty1 screen and I can freely switch between tty1-7 except tty7 is blank instead of the GUI. I would like to attempt to repair this failed upgrade if at all possible. After consulting some related threads I used the command

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and I get back

```
setting up resolvconf (1.77untu1) ...
Processing triggers for resolvconf (1.77ubuntu1) ...
resolconf: Error: /run/resolvconf/interface either does not exist or is not a directory
dpkg: error processing package resolvconf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 resolvconf
```

Any other commands related to repairing the upgrade returned similar errors with regards to "resolvconf", but I'm happy to post details on whatever you want.

Any thoughts on how to proceed? I would like to avoid completely reinstalling and losing un-backed-up data.

Thanks.